# Randomize n unique number

Tags: sas

No idea why, but I'm really struggling with this one.
I'm trying to get n unique numbers.
On this example, I want it to be 15 number;

```
    %let maximum_draws = 15;
```

Whatever I tried (and I'm on this for couple of hours, I get duplicates).
Could someone please explain why?

```
    data test;
    array game(&maximum_draws);
    game(1) = int(ranuni(0)*15+1);
    do i = 2 to &maximum_draws;
        rand = int(ranuni(0)*15+1);
        do j = 1 to i-1;
            if rand eq game(j) then do while (rand eq game(j));
                rand = int(ranuni(0)*15+1);
            end;
        end;
        game(i) = rand;
    end;
    run;
```

Comment: You're only ensuring that the rand at every "i" is different from "i-1".  You can't just check (rand eq gam(j)), you have to check all previous, each time you reset.

Comment: I think I get it. Thank you for your help, Jeff! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a more efficient test to check whether the number has already been picked, using the `not in` operator:

```
data test;
array game(&maximum_draws);
do i = 1 to &maximum_draws;
    do while (game(i) = .);
        rand = int(ranuni(0)*15+1);
        if rand not in game then game(i) = rand;
    end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Also, note that if &maximum_draws is higher than the highest possible rand, the code will hang.  I'm guessing you want to change the hard-coded 15s to macro references too.

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you're sure you have a relatively small (ie, not billions or something) is to explicitly create the values and then pick from them.

```
%let maximum_draws=15;
%let draws=10;

data population;
  do game = 1 to &maximum_Draws.;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc surveyselect data=population out=games n=&draws;
run;
```

SAS does the work for you this way.

Comment: Never heard of  surveyselect  before. Thanks, Joe!